# Validate form and stay on the same page with same parameters

Tags: php, validation

So i want to validate some form fields and if there are errors, they should be displayed in the same page with the same url including parameters, it does validate them but when it redirects to the same page the URL loses it's parameters and doesn't display what it needs, i get the id_carte=2 with `$id_carte = $_GET['id_carte'];`

- URL before form action:
  http://localhost/project/components/carte.php?id_carte=2
- URL after form action with succesful validation: http://localhost/project/components/carte.php

which screws with whats being displayed on that page

```
<form class="carte-coment-box" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input class="coment-box-input" type="text" name="nume_utilizator" placeholder="Nume">
    <input class="coment-box-input" type="email" name="adresa_email" placeholder="Email">

    <span class="width50 error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <span class="width50 error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

    <textarea class="width100 coment-box-textarea" name="comentariu" cols="45" placeholder="Adauga opinia ta despre carte" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
    <span class="width100 error"><?php echo $comentErr;?></span>

    <input type="hidden" name="id_carte" value="<?=$id_carte?>">
    <input class="btn btn-primary coment-box-btn" type="submit" value="Adauga">   
</form>
```

here is the validation

```
$name = $email  = $comment = "";
$nameErr = $emailErr = $comentErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["nume_utilizator"])) {
    $nameErr = "*Numele este necesar";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["nume_utilizator"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["adresa_email"])) {
    $emailErr = "*Emailul este necesar";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["adresa_email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comentariu"])) {
    $comentErr = "*Campul nu poate fi gol";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comentariu"]);
  }  
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

the result i'd like to get is something like

```
  if($nameErr === '' && $emailErr === '' && $comentErr === ''){
    //run adauga_comentariu.php as if it was in <form class="carte-coment-box" action="adauga_comentariu.php" method="POST">

  } else {
    //don't change URL, errors already are displayed as they should, ONLY problem is that the URL takes out the id_carte=2 which is necessary for rendering what it needs
  }
```

Comment: Can't you reload your page and feed the different fields directly with the info you had on previous form submit?
Example : you have a valid name, so you have the value in `$name`, but no valid email address, so you reload your form page, adding a "innerhtml" for example in the name field , feeding it with your `$name` value

Comment: You might consider using jquery Validation plugin.  It will let you do form validation without submitting your form until it passes validation.  It's still a good idea to validate your data on the server side before processing the data.